# Layer that is bigger than screen, but that you can move

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I need to put some sort of *layer* on my `CCScene` , which is a big image, bigger than the screen.
That I can move around, just with dragging my finger on screen. I **DON'T** need a `tiled map` . It's just for a menu .

So there should be an image, much bigger than the screen, that I can move around with some limits, and also set buttons on it later on.

Does the simpler approach is to set a `CClayer`, than when `touchMoved` method is called, just change its position?

Is there a class for that, that does not use the `tmx` files of tiled map ?

Answer (score 0):

I would extend a CCNode for that (or layer if you prefer, but i personally tend to not extend sprite/layer/...), only CCNode.  Add the image. Then the menus. Register/deregister the node for touch handling (onEnter and onExit). This way, the entire thing moves around as one, and your touch handling becomes simplified. You will need to clamp to prevent scrolling past the boundaries provided by the image.

When you got the thing working (clamped), you can later add ease'd movements for slick/smooth scrolling.

If with cocos2.1, extend CCNodeRGBA if you intend to fade or color the entire thing.